# Angular 6 lombok for reactive forms, any way to implement that behaviour?

Tags: angular, getter-setter, angular-reactive-forms, lombok

Normally I create a class for my reactive Forms and I create methods to access the properties forms, instead to do:

```
myForm.get('property').value
```

I create a getter-setter:

```
get property(){ return this.get('property').value;}
set property(value: type){ this.get('property').setValue(value);}
```

This way I'm able to do **myForm.property** any place I want.

Is there a way to place a decorator on the class? I want to magically create all that getter-setters as lombok for Java does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you add the decorator and make it work at runtime, it's not going to work as you expect with TypeScript: you're adding new props (get/set accessors) to the class and TS would not be able to conclude that. So you'd have to write out the type definition by hand anyway -- at this point, it's not really worth it.

So I guess the answer to your question is, unfortunatelly, "no".

However, you can utilize you IDE and create a shortcut for generating all this for you. For example, WebStorm offers "live templates", and you can make it somthing like this:

```
get $PROP(){ return this.get('$PROP').value;}
set $PROP(value: type){ this.get('$PROP').setValue(value);}
```

It will highlight the first `$PROP` and as yo type inside it, it willre-type the same thing across the other intances of `$PROP`.